# How to add an UIView on top of google map in iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, addition, drag

I am trying to place view on top of GMSMapView, so when the map is dragged, the view does not move. I tried to use 'addSubview' and 'insertSubview', but the view did not show up on top. Does anyone know what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Try adding your view, to the map super view. [map.superView addSubView: view]

Comment: Can you elaborate on who is the map superview?

Comment: Were you able to reslovle the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:yourView];
yourView.layer.zPosition = mapView.layer.zPosition + 1;
```

You may not have to add the view to the window, just add it to `map.superView` and try just adjusting the zPosition to the value above or maybe `1000` or something.